# Как правильно настроить htaccess в laravel

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

Нужно сделать редирект с www на без www и сделать редирект с http на https, с сохранением окончания ссылки

Редирект с www на без www

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC] 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Редирект с http на https

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Все редиректы работают, но почему-то режится окончание, например:
http://site.ru/contacts -> https://site.ru

Где теряется окончание?

Ещё в htaccess есть строки от laravel

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.(php|html|htm)(.*)\ HTTP/ 
 RewriteRule ^index.(php|html|htm)/?(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301]
```

При этом, параметры сохраняются, http://www.site.ru/contacts?test=1 -> https://site.ru/?test=1